# Reading JSON in jQuery and using the data?

Tags: jquery, json

I have a file in my /config directory named config.json.

```
{
  "general": {
    "name": "sequoia"
  }
}
```

How can I read this file in and access the name and apply it to the title of the page?

This is the code I have that isn't working:

```
if(Meteor.isClient) {
  $.getJSON("../config/config.json", function(data) {
    console.log(data.general.name);
  });
}
```

Help would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: It's not a valid `JSON`

Comment: Check out http://jsonlint.com/ for validating JSON. This looks to be valid.

Comment: It's valid.  I had a comma in front of "sequoia" but I removed it.

Comment: Are you receiving any errors? Is the request successful, receiving a `200 OK` status? Have you tried attaching a [`.fail()` callback](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/)?

Comment: I added the code I'm using.  Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Typed from memory, so may not run.. But this should log 'sequoia' to the console.. If it doesn't, try doing console.log(data) in chrome to see what's coming back. You may have a header/MIME-type issue on your webserver..

$.getJSON( "config/config.json", function( data ) {
  console.log(data.general.name);
  });

Comment: It's not logging it in the console.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: This is showing up in the console for the css files: Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html:

Comment: Are you seeing your config.json in the resource list (or in the network tab if using chrome)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.